# convert a query from Sqlite3 to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have converted my database from Sqlite3 to mysql, but when I try to execute a this query:

```
SELECT * from main WHERE case_id IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT case_id FROM main WHERE subject LIKE '%word%' AND 
court = 'other'  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY case_id, date;
```

that worked on sqlite3, i get the following error on MySql:

```
 #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

can anybody help me figure out a query that will work and produce same results? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT m1.*
from main m1
join 
(
   select case_id
   from main 
   where subject LIKE '%word%' 
   AND court = 'other'  
   ORDER BY RANDOM() 
   LIMIT 100
) m2 on m1.case_id = m2.case_id
ORDER BY m1.case_id, m1.date;
```